# Image rotation when you hover over it

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, hover

I have the following script where the user is supposed to hover over the image and then that image is rotated.

```js
$("#alcazar-image").rotate({
  bind:
  {
    mouseover : function() {
    $(this).rotate({animateTo:180})
  },
  mouseout : function() {
    $(this).rotate({animateTo:0})
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryrotate.com/js/jQueryRotateCompressed.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9 center-block" id="alcazar-row">
          <div class="media">
            <div class="media-left media-middle">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://www.theo-android.co.uk/github-images/alcazar.png" class="media-object img-thumbnail" id="alcazar-image" alt="alcazar">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
                <div class="media-heading"><h3>Alcazar Park</h3></div>
                <p style="font-size:20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <p style="text-align:left"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#alcazarModal"> More&raquo;</a></p>   
            </div>
              
            </div>  
    </div>
```

However,the hovering effect doesn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Theo.

Comment: why u need js for it. You can do this with css also

Comment: I know,but I want to improve my jquery skills.

Comment: Seems to work after i added jquery to your snippet

Comment: yes. its working.

Comment: @Theo Try run it and tell me if that is not what you want

Comment: @Theo I think you might a have reference error in your page, Either your `Jquery` or rotate script is not added correctlty

Comment: It's working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is good except you forgot to include jquery and jquery-rotate plugin in code snippet, try playing with below's code :

```js
$("#alcazar-image").rotate({
  bind: {
    mouseover: function() {
      $(this).rotate({
        animateTo: 180
      })
    },
    mouseout: function() {
      $(this).rotate({
        animateTo: 0
      })
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/wilq32/jqueryrotate/master/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9 center-block" id="alcazar-row">
  <div class="media">
    <div class="media-left media-middle">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://www.theo-android.co.uk/github-images/alcazar.png" class="media-object img-thumbnail" id="alcazar-image" alt="alcazar">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
      <div class="media-heading">
        <h3>Alcazar Park</h3>
      </div>
      <p style="font-size:20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p style="text-align:left"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#alcazarModal"> More&raquo;</a>
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to hear that. And no you can't accept all the answers here. Just choose the answer that really answers you question and solve the issues :) . As later on, others programmer will refer it when found its usefull

Answer (score 4):

You need not use JavaScript or jquery to achieve what you are trying to do here.

A simple css `transform: rotate` should do the job for you.

```css
img:hover {
  transform: rotate(720deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(720deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(720deg);
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryrotate.com/js/jQueryRotateCompressed.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9 center-block" id="alcazar-row">
  <div class="media">
    <div class="media-left media-middle">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://www.theo-android.co.uk/github-images/alcazar.png" class="media-object img-thumbnail" id="alcazar-image" alt="alcazar">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
      <div class="media-heading">
        <h3>Alcazar Park</h3>
      </div>
      <p style="font-size:20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p style="text-align:left"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#alcazarModal"> More&raquo;</a>
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in CSS.

```
img{
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform .8s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;


}
img:hover{
    transform:rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using the [`.hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) event with [rotate](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp):

```
$("#alcazar-image").hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("rotate-180");
});
```

[JsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g56xq1tL/1/)

Answer (score 1):

just replace your jQuery with this ::

```
$("#alcazar-image").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(180deg)');
    $(this).css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(180deg)'); /* IE 9 */
    $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(180deg)'); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
    $(this).css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(0deg)'); /* IE 9 */
    $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(0deg)'); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
});
```

It will work perfectly to all browser.